# ASEF: принцип формирования фильтра

Tags: c++, алгоритм, opencv

Пытаюсь разобраться в принципе формирования [Average of Synthetic Exact Filter](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=9BD643997B1A40DB23A03018E31950E9?doi=10.1.1.492.7927&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Для OpenCV существует [реализация использования](https://github.com/laoyang/ASEF) данного типа фильтров на примере детекции зрачка человеческого глаза. Алгоритм запатентован, общественности предоставлен только лишь уже готовый классификатор.

Как и во всех подобных алгоритмах, нацеленных на детекцию объектов, обучение производится на ряде изображений, но при этом на одном и том же кадре (обучающем материале) должны находиться как позитив, так и негатив совместно. На сколько я понял, алгоритм неинвариантен к масштабированию объектов (размер всегда должен быть почти одинаков), но при этом более вариантен к ротации (повороту), буде обучающие материалы с такими углами будут представлены в выборке.

Интересен прежде всего сам принцип обучения, хотя бы в общих чертах. Буду признателен за любую помощь по данному вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что весь процесс обучения, если кратко, сводится к следующему:

1. берётся исходное изображение;
2. берётся изображение размером с исходное и из него делается маска, где фон имеет нулевое значение, а объект с настраиваемым радиусом отмечается, скажем, белым кругом;
3. над обоими производится БПФ;
4. БПФ маски делится на БПФ исходника и ОБПФ полученного результата;
5. переход к первому пункту с тем, чтобы обработать все исходники;
6. из полученных результатов вычисляется среднее - это и есть искомый фильтр.

Конечно, в дополнение применяются ещё определённые оптимизации, но в целом, похоже, именно так.

**Update.** Если делать так, то ничего не выйдет. Причина этому в деталях, а о них в подобных документах обычно ничего не говорят. Часто обоснованно, ввиду очевидности.

```
// Преобразование Фурье. Обёртка над функцией OpenCV "dft".
cv::Mat fdft(const cv::Mat &src_mat, const cv::Size &size) {
    const int rs = size.height - src_mat.rows;
    const int cs = size.width  - src_mat.cols;

    cv::Mat pad_mat;
    cv::copyMakeBorder(src_mat, pad_mat, 0, rs, 0, cs
        , cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));

    const std::vector<cv::Mat> channels {
        pad_mat, cv::Mat::zeros(pad_mat.size(), CV_64F)
    };

    cv::Mat dft_mat;
    cv::merge(channels, dft_mat);
    cv::dft(dft_mat, dft_mat, 0, src_mat.rows);

    return dft_mat;
}

// Обратное преобразование Фурье. Такая же обёртка.
cv::Mat idft(const cv::Mat &dft_mat, const cv::Size &size) {
    const int flags
        = cv::DFT_INVERSE | cv::DFT_SCALE | cv::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT;

    cv::Mat dst_mat;
    cv::dft(dft_mat, dst_mat, flags, size.height);

    return dst_mat(cv::Rect(cv::Point(0,0),size));
}

// Деление матриц комплексных чисел друг на друга
// (используется на последнем шаге при получении фильтра).
cv::Mat div(const cv::Mat &mat1, const cv::Mat &mat2) {
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels1;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels2;

    cv::split(mat1, channels1);
    cv::split(mat2, channels2);

    cv::divide(channels1[0], channels2[0], channels1[0], 1, -1);
    cv::divide(channels1[1], channels2[0], channels1[1], 1, -1);

    cv::Mat dst_mat;
    cv::merge(channels1, dst_mat);

    return dst_mat;
}

// Создание фильтра.
void createFilter() {
    // Потребуется ниже.
    cv::Mat sum1_dft_mat, sum2_dft_mat;

    // Пример берёт кадры из видео, но, очевидно,
    // можно использовать и просто набор изображений.
    cv::VideoCapture cap("input.avi");
    if(cap.isOpened() == false) return;

    while(1) {
        // Получаем кадр.
        cv::Mat src_mat; cap >> src_mat;
        if(src_mat.empty() == true) break;

        // Осуществляем предварительную обработку.
        // Помимо обычного в таких случаях удаления цифрового шума
        // через размытие с малым ядром, можно добавить что-нибудь
        // вроде адаптивного выравнивания гистограммы с тем, чтобы
        // повысить контрастность в критичных участках входного
        // изображения. Впрочем, это уже надо смотреть по месту.
        cv::Mat gry_src_mat;
        cv::cvtColor(src_mat, gry_src_mat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::blur(gry_src_mat, gry_src_mat, cv::Size(3,3));
        gry_src_mat.convertTo(gry_src_mat, CV_64F);

        // Хороший инструмент в OpenCV. Одна строка, и пользователь
        // программы может указать центральную точку искомого объекта
        // на входном изображении.
        const cv::Rect roi = cv::selectROI(gry_src_mat, true, true);

        // Координаты центра объекта. Нет необходимости в очень
        // точном целеуказании, однако и сильно промахиваться
        // тоже не стоит.
        const int x = roi.x + (roi.width / 2);
        const int y = roi.y + (roi.height / 2);
        if(x == 0 || y == 0) continue;

        // 2D гауссиана в зависимости от радиуса и применённая к
        // исходному изображению осуществляет размытие последнего,
        // а также центрирует отмеченный на изображении объект при
        // вычислении корреляции.
        const double radius = 3.

        cv::Mat gry_msk_mat = cv::Mat::zeros(gry_src_mat.size(), CV_64F);

        for(int row = 0, rows = gry_msk_mat.rows; row < rows; ++row) {
            for(int col = 0, cols = gry_msk_mat.cols; col < cols; ++col) {
                const double n
                    = std::pow(double(col-x), 2.0)
                        + std::pow(double(row-y), 2.0);

                const double d = std::pow(radius, 2.0);

                gry_msk_mat.at<double>(row,col)
                    = std::exp((n/d) * -1.);
            }
        }

        // Осуществляем преобразование Фурье.
        const cv::Mat dft_src_mat = fdft(gry_src_mat, gry_src_mat.size());
        const cv::Mat dft_msk_mat = fdft(gry_msk_mat, gry_msk_mat.size());

        // Производим перемножение спектров и вычисляем корреляцию
        // созданной маски и входного изображения, а также входного
        // изображения к самому себе.
        cv::Mat cor1_dft_mat, cor2_dft_mat;
        cv::mulSpectrums(dft_msk_mat, dft_src_mat, cor1_dft_mat, 0, true);
        cv::mulSpectrums(dft_src_mat, dft_src_mat, cor2_dft_mat, 0, true);

        // Простое поэлементное суммирование ранее полученных матриц.
        sum1_dft_mat = (sum1_dft_mat.empty() == false)
            ? sum1_dft_mat + cor1_dft_mat : cor1_dft_mat;
        sum2_dft_mat = (sum2_dft_mat.empty() == false)
            ? sum2_dft_mat + cor2_dft_mat : cor2_dft_mat;
    }

    if(sum1_dft_mat.empty() == false && sum2_dft_mat.empty() == false) {
        // Для вычисления итогового фильтра важно правильно произвести
        // деление полученных на предыдущем этапе матриц друг на друга.
        cv::Mat dft_flt_mat = div(sum1_dft_mat, sum2_dft_mat);

        // Последний шаг, если хотим увидеть полученный результат.
        cv::Mat gry_flt_mat = idft(dft_flt_mat, dft_flt_mat.size());
        ...
    }
}
```

Если вывести `gry_flt_mat`, то можно получить что-то вроде такого при условии обучения, например, на зрачок глаза:

[image: изображение фильтра]

Пользоваться просто. Применяем ко входному изображению ту же самую предварительную обработку, которую осуществляли при тренировке, затем осуществляем преобразование Фурье, а в конце - корреляцию:

```
cv::mulSpectrums(dft_src_mat, dft_flt_mat, cor_dft_mat, 0, true);
```

Полученная `cor_dft_mat` будет содержать яркий пик в том месте входного изображения, где есть совпадение с объектом, на который был натренирован фильтр:

[image: Отклик фильтра]